# how to set focus on a specific html element per demand (angular)

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular form which has "self-build" grid of rows and cells (using angular-material). The grid is dynamic and can be very long\wide.
I have a reference to every cell binded to that grid(meaning, I can control its properties and control the view of it).
I need a way to put focus on a specific cell, per demand, and that the page will change its position so that the cell will be in the middle of the page.
Using viewChild is problematic because the cells are being built based on an unknown dataset

Comment: How does your code look, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpfull:
ts file:

```
@ViewChild("name") nameField: ElementRef;
  editName(): void {
    this.nameField.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

html file:

```
<div class="group">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input #name matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="editName()">Edit</button>
</div>
```

more info : [Link](https://codeburst.io/focusing-on-form-elements-the-angular-way-e9a78725c04f)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not answering the need - I have a grid that is loaded from a data structure- I need reference to all its cells which are not known - so I can not set the ViewChild value in advance. The grid can contain more than 1000 cells

Answer (score 0):

For our dynamic form i use this [article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3376-creating-an-input-driven-autofocus-directive-in-angular-5-0-2.htm):

first define an AppAutoFocusDirective:

```
// Import the core angular services.
import { AfterContentInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

var BASE_TIMER_DELAY = 10;

@Directive({
    selector: "[autofocus], [appAutofocus]",
    inputs: [
        "shouldFocusElement: appAutofocus",
        "timerDelay: autofocusDelay"
    ]
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

    public shouldFocusElement: any;
    public timerDelay: number | string;

    private elementRef: ElementRef;
    private timer: number;

    // I initialize the autofocus directive.
    constructor( elementRef: ElementRef ) {

        this.elementRef = elementRef;

        this.shouldFocusElement = "";
        this.timer = null;
        this.timerDelay = BASE_TIMER_DELAY;

    }

    // ---
    // PUBLIC METHODS.
    // ---

    // I get called once after the contents have been fully initialized.
    public ngAfterContentInit() : void {

        // Because this directive can act on the stand-only "autofocus" attribute or
        // the more specialized "appAutofocus" property, we need to check to see if the
        // "shouldFocusElement" input property is the empty string. This will signify
        // that the focus it not being data-driven and should be performed automatically.
        if ( this.shouldFocusElement === "" ) {

            this.startFocusWorkflow();

        }

    }


    // I get called every time the input bindings are updated.
    public ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ) : void {

        // If the timer delay is being passed-in as a string (ie, someone is using
        // attribute-input syntax, not property-input syntax), let's coalesce the
        // attribute to a numeric value so that our type-annotations are consistent.
        if ( changes.timerDelay && ( typeof( this.timerDelay ) !== "number" ) ) {

            // If the coalesce fails, just fall-back to a sane value.
            if ( isNaN( this.timerDelay = +this.timerDelay ) ) {

                this.timerDelay = BASE_TIMER_DELAY;

            }

        }

        // If the focus input is being data-driven, then we either need to start the
        // focus workflow if focus is required; or, clear any existing workflow if focus
        // is no longer required (so that we don't steal focus from another element).
        if ( changes.shouldFocusElement ) {

            ( this.shouldFocusElement )
                ? this.startFocusWorkflow()
                : this.stopFocusWorkflow()
            ;

        }

    }


    // I get called once when the directive is being unmounted.
    public ngOnDestroy() : void {

        this.stopFocusWorkflow();

    }

    // ---
    // PRIVATE METHODS.
    // ---

    // I start the timer-based workflow that will focus the current element.
    private startFocusWorkflow() : void {

        // If there is already a timer running for this element, just let it play out -
        // resetting it at this point will only push-out the time at which the focus is
        // applied to the element.
        if ( this.timer ) {

            return;

        }

        this.timer = setTimeout(
            () : void => {

                this.timer = null;
                this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();

            },
            this.timerDelay
        );

    }


    // I stop the timer-based workflow, preventing focus from taking place.
    private stopFocusWorkflow() : void {

        clearTimeout( this.timer );
        this.timer = null;

    }

}
```

Then set index for every cell in the grid and manage current cell that has focus now,
for example we have two for loop and two index i&j for them,

```
<my-first-element *ngFor="let f of columns; let i=index">
     <my-second-element *ngFor="let f of columns; let j=index">
          <my-element [appAutofocus]="j===0 && i===0"> </my-element>
     </my-second-element>
</my-first-element>
```

see this example [ex1](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/autofocus-angular5/)